# When it comes the average lifetime of chemicals in the atmosphere, is the mean lifetime ~1.4427 times the half-life? As with radioactivity?

Tags: atmosphere, climate-change, atmospheric-chemistry, global-weirding

There are so many websites giving numbers for 'average' lifetimes of global-warming or ozone-depleting chemicals in the atmosphere, yet they are rarely explicit in their definition(s)...

For instance, methane is usually stated to last 12.4 years....  But is this half-life (of a large amount) or mean lifetime (of a single molecule)?

Comment: That would only hold for purely exponential decay. ["To evaluate the total greenhouse effect of a given gas molecule, one needs to know, first, how long it remains in the atmosphere and, second, how it interacts chemically with other molecules. This effect is calculated by injecting a pulse of that gas (e.g., 1 Tg) into the atmosphere and watching the added abundance decay as simulated in a CTM. This decay is represented by a sum of exponential functions, each with its own decay time."](https://archive.ipcc.ch/ipccreports/tar/wg1/133.htm)

Comment: a part of the answer to this is in your question,for gasses"average LIFETIME" and for radioactivity "Half-Life".